# Unable get props value in data After i upgrade vue-cli

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-cli-4, vue-property-decorator

My `Vue` version is 2.6.14, and the `vue-property-decorator` version is 9.1.2. Yesterday, I upgraded vue-cli 3 to version 4 using vue upgrade. Previously, my code was working fine, but after the upgrade, there is a problem. I cannot directly assign the value of props to data in the child component during initialization.

the code was:

```
  @Prop()
  cropperOption!: Partial<Cropper.Options>

  defaultCropperOptions: any = {
    test: (() => {
      console.log('this.cropperOption: ', this.cropperOption)
      return 1
    })(),
    ...this.cropperOption
  }
```

Before the upgrade the console was:
// this.cropperOption: { ratio: 1 }

After the upgrade the console is:
// this.cropperOption: undefined

And I found that when I changed the `target` in the `tsconfig.json` file from `esnext` to `es6`, the console of this code returned like before the upgrade. But i dont know why, the `target` has always been `esnext` before the upgrade.

I don't know what caused this change. Does anyone know?